# Do Fifa Prime Gaming FUT Packs expire if I don't open them?

Tags: amazon-prime-gaming, fifa-22

I redeemed several Prime Gaming Packs for Fifa22 in these months, but never opened one since I didn't own the game. Unless, in may, it came for free with PS+ subscription.

The other day I downloaded the game in order to open those packs, only to see that I had just the last Prime Gaming Pack in my inventory.

Did I miss all the previous redeemed ones? Do rewards just expire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post #7 in this [EA Support Post](https://answers.ea.com/t5/Hockey-Ultimate-Team/Do-packs-expire/td-p/10882565) for ultimate hockey team suggests:

> It's stated in the Terms and Conditions that they will be replaced by the next set of packs.

This is for NHL 22, but it stands to reason that EA would use the same model for all of their monthly promotions. I can't find any explicit information about Prime Packs in FIFA 22 expiring anywhere on the internet, but they **are** monthly (similar to the "Diamond Choice" packs from the support post).

So, yes, I'm afraid your Prime Gaming Packs expired.

Comment: D'oh. Yes, this is probably true for Fifa, too.